# How to add partialview to insert data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have two tables Category and Product.

```
Category:- CategoryId,CategoryName
Product:- ProductId, ProductName, Price, CategoryId(FK)
```

I want to add data from a single view.
I create category as a partial view and render it to Create page.

Controller is:-

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private StoreDbEntities db = new StoreDbEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Product/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var products = db.products.Include(p => p.Category);
        return View(products.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Product/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        product product = db.products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(product);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Product/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult CreateCategory()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateCategory(Category category)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Categories.Add(category);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        return View(category);
    }
    //
    // POST: /Product/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName", product.CategoryId);
        return View(product);
    }
```

}

and Create View is:-

```
    @model MvcApplication9.Models.Category

@Html.Partial("_Category",Model);

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Category</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and _Categoy View is:-

```
@model MvcApplication9.Models.Category

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Category</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

When I run it show error  "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.". Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What error, and in which view?

Comment: Your question is not structured correctly. Where do you get the error?Where do you call the partial view? The first mistake I see is - you should put your scripts in the layout. You cannot include scripts inside a partial view and as you did it the "_Categoy View" won't be rendered as partial, because its missing the unobtrusive.js

Comment: _Categoy View is my partial view. I call it on Create View. I have script on layout but I did not mention it hear. I got the error is: "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."

Comment: can you remove all the unnecessary code from the question? also the views seem to be exactly the same. `EntityValidationErrors` is an `EF` my guess i that the FK `CategoryId` is missing from the `Product` model when it's posted to the controller.

Comment: On create View I add the partial view @Html.Partial("_Category",Model);